# Quadratics Word Problem

Tags: quadratics, word-problem

The path of a football flying through the air can be modelled by a quadratic equation. The football reaches the ground after 12 seconds in flight and is kicked from a height of 1 meter. The parabola has undergone a vertical reflection and a vertical compression by a factor of 1/6.

a) Write an equation to represent the path of the football.

b) Does the football reach a height of 8 meters?

*Please, if you can, explain in simple language and step by step.*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Putting that into your question statement will improve it.

Comment: Also, given that this is a physics problem, you should definitely include the kinematic equations and $g=9.81$ m/s^2 as relevant context.

Comment: @Semiclassical This is not a physics problem, it's straight out of the math textbook. That's all there is to it, no more no less. The question is as it is in the textbook.

Comment: What is vertical reflection and vertical compression?  That something like $g(x) = -1/6\,f(x)\quad$?

Comment: @DanielV http://www.benettonplay.com/toys/flipbookdeluxe/player.php?id=406903 <<<-----VERTICAL COMPRESSION    http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP9/funclesson1.htm <<<<<----REFLECTION

Comment: I think in this case the 1/6 simply represents the a value of a quadratic equation. 1 is the y-intercept, and 12 is the one of the x-intercepts.

Comment: Is your question also from that website?  A link might be helpful in understanding what the question was attempting to ask.

Comment: No it's from my textbook, a homework question. What it's trying to ask is what is the equation (in standard form/vertex/intercept) of the described parabola. The difficult thing here is that not all the parts are given, that is they gave the a value, one of the x-intercepts, the y-intercept of the parabola. Though for ex. to write the equation in the vertex form you will need the coordinates of the vertex or if you will want to write in in intercept form you will need the second x-coordinate. So you somehow have to figure the unknown value and then write the equation of the parabola.

Comment: @Simon Check out my answer and post comment there if you have more questions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what they mean:

A parabola is characterized by 3 coefficients, so you need 3 pieces of information to determine a parabola.  Two of the pieces of information are given directly, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(12) = 0$.

For the third, it seems they are attempting to say that a unit parabola was shifted so that the leading coefficient was scaled from $A=1$ to $A=-1/6$.  So you have:

$$f(t) = At^2 + Bt + C \tag{1}$$
$$\begin{cases} A=-\frac 16 \\ f(0) = 1 \\ f(12) = 0\end{cases}$$

Can you take it from here?

---

You know that $A = -1/6$, so **(1)** becomes:

$$f(t) = -\frac16t^2 + Bt + C \tag{2}$$

Now you know that $f(0) = 1$, so **(2)** becomes

$$f(0) = -\frac160^2 + B\cdot 0 + C$$
$$1 = 0 + 0 + C$$
$$1 = C$$
So
$$f(t) = -\frac16t^2 + Bt + 1\tag{3}$$

Now you just have to find out the value of $B$, so use $f(12) = 0$ **(3)**:

$$f(12) = -\frac16\cdot 12^2 + B\cdot12 + 1$$
$$0 = -\frac{144}{6} + 12 B + 1$$
$$23 = 12 B$$
$$\frac{23}{12} = B$$

So

$$f(t) = -\frac16 t^2 + \frac{23}{12} t + 1$$

Now you know the equation of the height of the football.  Then the question becomes, does it ever reach a height of 8m?  So set:

$$8 = -\frac16 t^2 + \frac{23}{12} t + 1$$

and solve for $t$ using the quadratic equation.  You want to check if there is a positive real number that solves the equation.

Comment: Not exactly, I mean, what do I do with this information, I already knew it before... I am supposed to plug in the known values into the standard form equation?

Comment: You want to find $A$, $B$, and $C$.  You are given $A$.  use $f(0) = 1$ to find the value of $C$.  Then you only have 1 variable left $B$, so use $f(12) = 0$ to find that value.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this? I'm confused

Comment: Where do I place the values/plug them in?

Comment: @Simon Ok check it now and see if you understand.

Comment: Thank you! I understand this now! :)